# Aurelia Select Not Binding Properly

Tags: javascript, select, data-binding, aurelia

I have the following component:

```
import {inject, customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {I18N} from 'aurelia-i18n';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import {HubFactory} from 'service';
import {hub} from 'enums';

@customElement('language-switcher')
@inject(Element, I18N, Router, HubFactory)
export class LanguageSwitcher {
  languageMatcher = (a, b) => {console.log(a,b); a.id === b.id;}

  @bindable languages = [];
  @bindable selectedLanguage = {};


  constructor(element, i18n, router, hubFactory) {
    this.element = element;
    this.i18n = i18n;
    this.router = router;
    this.usmHub = hubFactory.getHub(hub.usersSessionManagementHub);
  }


  switchLanguage() {
    ...
  }
}
```

with the following template:

```
<template>
  <form role="language" class="navbar-form navbar-left m-t-1">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select value.bind="selectedLanguage" change.delegate="switchLanguage()" matcher.bind="languageMatcher" class="form-control">
        <option repeat.for="language of languages" model.bind="language">${language.shortName}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

which is used like this in the parent view:

```
<language-switcher languages.bind="languages" selectedLanguage.bind="selectedLanguage"></language-switcher>
```

The problem I have is that the select doesn't use the selectedLanguage as the default selected option and in the matcher function logs the default empty object for b instead. The a object is logged properly.

In the parent VM both the languages and the selectedLanguage are computed as follows and both return a value when I inspect them:

```
get languages() {
    return this.session.getSupportedLanguages();
  }

  get selectedLanguage() {
    return this.session.getDefaultLanguage();
  }
```

The languages get populated properly, however the selected language does not. Both methods in the session object point to the same array. Please advise as to what I am doing wrong.

Each language has an id property.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When binding to a mixed-case property (eg `@bindable selectedLanguage`), use kebab case (eg `selected-language.bind="..."`). This is required because the DOM automotically lower-cases everything.
2. When declaring a bindable property that serves as a "value", set it's default binding-mode to "two way". This way you can use `.bind` in your templates and will not need to remember to explicitly two-way bind to the property using `.two-way="..."`:

   ```
   @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) defaultLanguage;
   ```
3. Make sure your matcher function returns true/false. Your matcher is missing a `return` statement!

Here's a running example with all three issues fixed: https://gist.run/?id=9f96ac9d135fb39f4b7c172a23e6859c

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jeremy. I got it to work yesterday, but the additional information is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just realized that I need to use kebab case for the selectLanguage bindable attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in your code:

1 - Binding HTML expressions should be converted to kebab case. So, instead of

```
selectedLanguage.bind="selectedLanguage"
```

you should use:

```
selected-language.bind="selectedLanguage"
```

2 - Any reasons for using getters? You could bind the property directly:

Running example https://gist.run/?id=bcd7841ed21616136d5b6ab259a9d9c2